# Algebraic number with bounded coefficients

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics, rational-numbers

How many algebraic numbers $z$ are there satisfying $P(z)=0$ where $P(z)$ is some polynomial with integer coefficients of degree less than or equal to $n$ such that the absolute value of every coefficient is less than or equal to $x$?

In other words, define a function $N(x,n)$ as the number of such algebraic numbers as described above. What conclusions, particularly asymptotic, can we draw about $N(x,n)$? Can we extend $N(x,n)$ to real or complex values of $x,n$?

Clearly $N(x,0)=1$ for all $x$. Can we find a closed form for $N(x,1)$, the number of rational number with numerator and denominator less than or equal to $x$? An asymptotic formula? What if we were to hold $x$ constant with $n$ variable? Clearly $N(x,n)$ grows quickly in both variables.

I can't see how to attack this function. Anyone have any ideas?

(Sorry about tagging, there don't seem to be many appropriate ones.)

Comment: Just to clarify: by "..that the absolute value of every coefficient is less than or equal to $x$" do you actually mean that each coefficient written in their lowest terms has both the denominator and numerator less than or equal to $x$? Your third paragraph seems to suggest this (and the question makes more sense that way as well), but it's not entirely clear if that's what you mean.

Comment: I suppose $x$ is an integer in your question ? Then N(1,x) would be obviously $O(x^2)$. Getting a tight bound looks pretty cumbersome but interesting. Notice that for a general $n$, the number of zeroes of a polynomial of degree n is $\le n$, so a large bound should always be $O(n x^{n+1})$.

Comment: Actually, for $n=1$, you should be able to get a closed asymptotic form using the following result : the number of $(a,b)$ with $a,b$ positive and lower than $n$ where $a,b$ are coprime is equivalent to $\frac 6 {\pi^2} n^2$ (you find that playing with integer convolution and the Euler $\phi$ function).

Comment: @relep: I intended that $P$ have integer coefficients, and have changed the question to reflect such. What I meant in the third paragraph is that $N(x,1)$ is the number of zeros of linear functions (with integer coefficients $\le x$), i.e. the number of rational numbers with numerator an denominator $\le x$.

Comment: @AlexH. Thank you, that is exactly the kind of thing that I'm looking for in terms of asymptotic results. Are similar results possible for higher $n$?

Comment: @Laertes: see the full $x=1$ case below. For a higher $x$, I doubt you can find a closed tight form as you would have to count  all polynomials $a_0+...+a_nX^n$ with $\text{gcd}(a_i) =1$ and then eliminate all algebraic numbers which are zeroes of two different polynomials (e.g. $\sqrt{2}$ is a zero for $X^2-2$ and for $X^4-4$). Maybe try to have a crack at the case $x=2$ as you have a relatively simple closed form for zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the note, pick $m \ge 1$. $N(1,m)$ is the number of zeroes of polynomials of the form $aX+b$ with $a,b \in I_m=\{-m,-m+1,...0,m-1,m\}$, i.e. the number of rationals $p/q$ with $p,q \in I_m$.

You can focus on the $(p,q)$ where $p,q \ge 0$ (you just need to multiply the result by two to take into account the negatives) and $\text{gcd}(p,q)=1$ (the other ones would be double-counting).

As hinted below, $J_k = \text{Card}\{(p,q) \;\; \text{s.t.} \;\; p,q \in \{1,...,k\}, \text{gcd}(p,q)=1\} \sim \frac{6}{\pi^2}k^2 $ as $k \to \infty$. That should imply: $$N(1,m) \sim \frac {12} {\pi^2} m^2 \simeq 1.22\, m^2$$

To get the result above, you need [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution), [Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series) and the [Moebius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function).

Write

- $J_k = 2 \text{ Card }\{(p,q) \; ; \; 1 \le p \le q \le k,\; \text{gcd}(p,q)=1\} = 2\sum_{q=1}^k \varphi(q)$
- use $\mu \star \text{id} = \varphi$ to get to $\displaystyle \sum_1^N \varphi(n) = \sum_d^N \sum_p^{N/d} \mu(d)p$
- with some work you get to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_1^N \varphi(n) \to  \sum^{\infty} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2)}$

Comment: How can the ratio $N(1,m)\over m^2$ be greater than $1$? Shouldn't it be $6\over \pi^2$?

Comment: Negative + positive numbers? (I may also have forgotten a 2 factor somewhere)

Comment: Hmm. Somehow I missed that.